# Why JQuery ready function is not called

Tags: jquery

I have a separate js file that loads after jquery file. I have following code in my javascript file

```
    $(document).ready(function()
{
    alert("Hello ready");
});
$(window).load(function () {
    alert("Hello load");
});
```

But only "Hello Load" alert is displayed and not "Hello ready". Can someone please guide me what's going wrong here ?

Comment: I thisnk you didn't include jquery libraray

Comment: any error in your browser console

Comment: Working sample - https://jsfiddle.net/nbmojbks/

Comment: Edit your Q and give errors from console to us.

Comment: show us how you icluded the jquery lib

Comment: @JqueryKing JQuery library is added and thats why load code is working fine.

Comment: There is no error in console. My real problem is why load code is working and not ready code is working. If there is any problem with jquery then it should give me error in console and load code should not work